# Calling java code from java script in JSP

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

I am newbie in UI i.e. front end. I am using Javascript and JSP. I need to perform the below task.

I have a textarea in jsp page which gets populated from a text file which i read using Java. Now, I want to empty the text area and that text file on clicking a button. Emptying the file is not an issue only i don't get how to transfer call from jsp file to Servlet on clicking that button.

Please help.

Comment: response.sendRedirect("ProjectName/ServletName?param1`=value1")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to do this:

the classical way is form submission:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_form_processing.htm

e.g. you embedded a form in your jsp page that will send the data to your server when submitted.

the second way is via ajax

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)

I would suggest you google for the basics of form submission (which is not jsp specific) or doing ajax requests with javascript (with a library, for example jquery)

Answer (score 0):

there are two ways one by jsp and another by javascript

if the button is submit type and if you are using a form then

if the button is simple a button then

function x()
{
        window.location.replace("servlet name");
}

please tell me if you have any doubts

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do so.

1. use jquery and ajax, its so easy.

similar question here:
[jQuery Ajax POST example with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example)

you can find documentation here
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

2. or use JSNI.

   https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI